# How does the U.S. government "spend money into existence?"

Tags: government

What does that mean and how does it work? Are there other countries that do it?

I heard this phrase just now in this video. https://youtu.be/KxdU_wRCzYM

Update:
Here is a more direct link to where the phrase appears in the video, 20 seconds earlier to include context. https://youtu.be/KxdU_wRCzYM?t=574

Comment: Please be more clear (as in providing a link to where you heard that phrase, and a quote in context).

Comment: @RonJohn I updated my question with a link.

Comment: Hmm... I'm dubious whether they are an authoritative source.  A better plan would be to Google "spend money into existence" and then come back with questions.

Comment: @RonJohn I already Googled it but in that video when they said "spend money into existence" they also said something about how it first goes to or through the military and military contractors, my Google search didn't come up with anything about that. I trust Status Coup even more than I trust mainstream news outlets like NBC and FOX that are backed by big money which causes them to not explain things honestly and well.

Comment: The link is to a live feed, so it doesn't actually take us to a context where someone said this. But since it's a pair of guys doing a talk show the simple explanation is that they don't really know what they mean.

Comment: I’d say this is probably spam.

Comment: @DJClayworth I updated my question with a more direct link to where the phrase is used.

Comment: @quid more like Bad Economics.

Comment: You need to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_easing.

Comment: @RonJohn That article is about bank lending, here in the video he says that federal government spending is different from bank lending. https://youtu.be/KxdU_wRCzYM?t=890

Comment: Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: "was it an attempt to keep myself and others ignorant?"  Absolutely!!!  We're all part of the World Wide One World Zionist Conspiracy To Make Proles Into Sheeple.

Comment: **Or...**  it was closed because "This question needs details or clarity."

Comment: It would help if the video was quoted in the question text so we didn't have to watch the video.

Answer (score 3):

This is posited by [Stephanie Kelton in her book *The Deficit Myth*.](https://www.ft.com/content/673b0be2-3559-4b61-9224-7c271ae4ed31)

> Currency users must gather money before they spend it. You and I need to earn money or borrow it before we can buy goods and services, but the US government can simply spend money into existence: the Federal Reserve electronically credits bank accounts with brand new dollars. The government then taxes away the new money or exchanges it for US Treasuries, gathering back the tokens it creates. Spending thus comes before tax and borrowing, not after.

To understand it, you'll need to dig into [Modern Monetary Theory (MMT).](https://www.investopedia.com/modern-monetary-theory-mmt-4588060)

Comment: There's no free lunch; never has been, and never will be.  That means the US government will -- at some point soon after the petrodollar loses it's power -- have to pay the piper.

Comment: @RonJohn Oh, agreed. There's no ["magic pudding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Pudding).  What I've been looking for is that the MMT people say that inflation is still a problem... and I wonder whether the current round of inflation will kick in enough to put their theory seriously to the test.

Comment: @RonJohn Why do you think so? Only if there's too much money in circulation do they need to destroy some or spend less. If the exchange rate crashes it will affect everyone in the country equally.

Comment: @user253751 why do I think there's no free lunch?

Comment: @RonJohn what do you think the free lunch is?

Comment: @user253751 deficit spending.

Comment: @RonJohn if managed correctly, it is free because it puts otherwise unused resources to their proper use, increasing output.

Comment: @user253751 I think that's divorced from reality.

Comment: @RonJohn Well, economists disagree with you. You are telling me a common ideology, which is generally considered false except among the people who happen to hold it. The fact is that the private sector does not always achieve full productivity - in a recession, for example. The government can flatten out a recession by, essentially, buying the things that consumers are no longer buying, using made-up money. (This only addresses the real economy part of the recession. Other measures will be needed to prevent it from eroding everyone's retirement savings)

Comment: @user253751 I'm sure that *some* economists are divorced from reality; I'd even believe that *a generation of economists* have been taught to be divorced from reality.  But just as "rational man" is arrant nonsense, so is the notion that there's a free lunch.

Comment: @RonJohn It's not free. People have to physically work to produce the stuff the government wants to them to. But the alternative is them being unemployed, and in our economic system, that's worse.